# Pass many arguments from controller to service using spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using MVC with spring so i want to pass some parameters from my controller, this fields get from my submit form, my question is which the best way for pass this fields , through bean form send to service or create  another bean .

```
    @Autowired
    RegisterServiceImpl registerServiceImpl;

    @RequestMapping(value="/registeruser", method = RequestMethod.POST )
    public String register( @ModelAttribute(value = "registerForm") RegisterForm registerForm , ModelMap model{

         //previous method extract each field from registerForm 
        //registerServiceImpl.registerUser(field1,field2,field3,fieldn);

        //actual method pass object registerForm
        registerServiceImpl.registerUser(registerForm);   

    }
```

The question is if pass RegisterForm to service class generate high coupling ? o which some alternative using a best practice for sucess low coupling .

Comment: Read up on the concept of Data Transfer Objects (DTOs).

Comment: For testability purpose, you might want to declare your service object as its interface type `RegisterService`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RegisterForm is indeed a DTO and as [vivin-paliath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263004/vivin-paliath) mentioned you might end in situations that just partial data from the DTO is useful, hence the need for converters.

I'd recommend the use of [Converters](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert) that spring provides, you just need to register your custom implementations and a single call to the conversion service does the trick keeping your code clean and decoupled from conversion logic.

Answer (score 0):

Whether `RegisterForm` will generator tight coupling depends on your use case. Is `RegisterServiceImpl#registerUser` used in multiple places? Will the `RegisterForm` type also benefit from reuse? If that is the case, there shouldn't be an issue, and you could use `RegisterForm` as a command object within the controller. In this scenario, `RegisterForm` is effectively a DTO.

However, you might end up in a situation where `RegisterForm` contains other details (perhaps used by other methods within `RegisterServiceImpl`) that will never come from the view, or if you need to perform some kind of translation/transformation of the data that comes from the view. If this is largely the case, I typically create a command object and then convert the information over from that object into an instance of `RegisterForm` and then pass that into the service.

Comment: Thans a lot for help , `RegisterForm` is used only for register user with this Form .